# Command-line arguments as functions in C

Tags: c, function, command-line-arguments

Can I directly use command-line arguments as parameters for other functions which I call in `main()`? Something like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    somefunction(argv[2], argv[3]);
}
```

Comment: There are some online c compilers, such as [ideone](http://ideone.com/) - check it out.

Comment: sure, why not? Just make sure that argc >= 4 (in your example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command line arguments are arguments of main.
Suppose a function like this:

```
func1(int a, char *s[])
{
}
```

Here a and s are arguments to function func1. They behave like local variables in the function. Now you can pass these variables to another function.  (like this: )

```
func1(int a, char *s[])
{
        func2(a, s);
}
```

So, answer to your question precisely is : yes.